# "Operation is not supported" with getComputedStyle

Tags: javascript, css, rotation, css-animations

I'm trying to get the current degrees from a rotaion-animation.
Sadly Firefox tells me the following:

```
NotSupportedError: Operation is not supported
[Break On This Error]   

var style = window.getComputedStyle(el);
```

el is the following:

```
document.getElementById('spinner');
```

And #spinner is and image which is rotated by an animation:

```
 @-moz-keyframes spinmerightroundbaby{
    0%{ -moz-transform: rotate(0deg); } 
    100%{ -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);}
    }
    #spinner{
        -moz-animation: spinmerightroundbaby 30s linear 0s infinite;
    }
```

No other JScode is executed.

Would you please help me out?

Comment: That error is caused by `el` being `null`. Your element `spinner` does not exist at run-time.

Comment: Ha! it can be that easy! Thanks I used the document.ready Method given by jQuery, now. That fixed it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Rob W reminded me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11482360/#comment15163431_11482360) to check if the Element is "null" and so it was.

Easy to fix: I used the [`$(document).ready()`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) function given by jQuery to defer the execution.
That worked fine.

Comment: it would be polite next time to give an opportunity to the person making a comment which resolves your Question to create an Answer so you can accept it when it pans out. Cheers!